# Globalisation & Localisation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, localization, asp.net-mvc-5

What is the Best way of implementing Localisation and Globalisation in .Net Web application other then using Resource files?

In Previous projects I had implemented using the resource file but now Client want to use different approach like managed through Database etc

Comment: declare the column datatype of the table to nvarchar whereever you want to store localized values

Answer (score 0):

Follow below points :

1. Isolate all user interface elements from the program source code.
       Put them in resource files, message files, or a private database.
2. Use the same resource identifiers throughout the life of the
   project. Changing identifiers makes it difficult to update localized
   resources from one build to another.
3. If used in multiple contexts, make multiple copies of the same
   string. The same string may have different translations in different
   contexts.
4. Only place strings requiring localization in resources. Leave
   non-localized strings as string constants in the source code.
5. Allocate text buffers dynamically since text size may expand when
   translated. If you must use static buffers, make them extra large
   (perhaps doubling the length of the English string) to accommodate
   localized strings.
6. Keep in mind that dialog boxes may expand due to localization. For
   example, a large dialog box that occupies the entire screen in
   low-resolution mode may require resizing to an unusable size when
   localized.

   7. Avoid text in bitmaps and icons, as these are difficult to localize.
      Do not create a text message dynamically at run time, either by
      concatenating multiple strings or by removing characters from static
      text. Word order varies by language, so dynamic composition of text
      in this manner requires code changes to localize to some languages.